# how can I add trading days?

Tags: r, date

for example in a date in thee form 07/03/2015 how can I add 30 trading days??

as.Date("07/03/2015", format="%d/%m/%Y") + 30
        [1] "2015-04-06"`

this take into account also Sundays and Saturdays how can I add only the trading days? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

Create data:

```
library(chron)
dates <- seq.dates("07/03/2015", by = "day", length = 30)
```

Generate weekdays:

```
dates <- weekdays(as.Date(dates))
```

Extract the days of the week:

```
remove <- c('Saturday', 'Sunday')
dates [! dates %in% remove]
```

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: I want display thee 30th trading day after "07/03/2015"